# Columns jumping to next row on small device in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a simple layout using Bootstrap 3, and it looks fine on laptop, but when I try to emulate in Chrome for small screen such as Iphone 5, one of my image is going to the next row, though I was expecting it to be at the same row as the heading. Visually, there seems to be enough space, and I tried pulling, pushing, applying offser but could not get it working yet.

Can anybody help point out please what am I doing wrong  here?

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-4 column"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 column"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-md-6 column">
            <img alt="300x200" src="images/loc.png" style="padding-top:15pt;height:auto;max-width:35px" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 column">
            <h2>Venue 2015</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what you defined. You allowed multiple columns only starting at `md`, so `sm` and `xs` will stay stacked.

Comment: Ouch... should rely on Bootstrap template generators lesser :( Thanks @PM77-1!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic (unanswerable) because the asker was not aware of a feature of the framework.

Comment: The fix was simply to define xs column where required:<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-4 column"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 column"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-xs-6 column">
            <img alt="300x200" src="images/loc.png" style="padding-top:15pt;height:auto;max-width:35px" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 column">
            <h2>Venue 2015</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html

Answer (score 1):

the col-md-* classes are only for screensizes from 992px to 1200px - if you want a 2-column-layout on small displays, add the col-xs-* classes.

In your case:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 column">
     <img alt="300x200" src="images/loc.png" style="padding-top:15pt;height:auto;max-width:35px" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 column">
      <h2>Venue 2015</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could write a function in Javascript that specifies the (smaller) sizes of specific elements if screen size is under a certain size. The full size image would still load, but the script would tell it to load width smaller width and height for smaller screen size.